# Count duplicate values in SSAS

Tags: ssas, cube, analysisservices

I have table Admission and Patient table. I build a cube as Admission table as fact table and Patient as dimension table. Now I want to count how many Patient_id in Admissions table. it is possible to do that in cube? Please do answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the `cube structure`, right click on the fact. Choose `new measure`. In the new window, select aggregate and field.

[image: CubeStructure]

[image: NewMeasure]

Comment: I see, it is possible to count duplicate patient_id in Admission table?

Comment: Add a field called `VisitNumber` to your table. Use MDX to select VisitNumber greater than 1